# Is there a way to have firebug show the Console and HTML windows at the same time?

Tags: firebug

I'm frequently testing code that manipulates the DOM. I can paste it and run it in the console
then switch to the HTML tab to see if it had the desired effect. Then when I switch back to the console view my code is gone and I have to re-paste it. This is a pain.

What I'd really like is to have the console in a right window and the HTML view in a left window. Then, presumably, I could (ideally) run my code and immediately see the effect on the HTML elements exposed in the left window.

Is there a way to do this? (or perhaps some extension for it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest alpha version of firebug 1.4 keeps the most recent code when you switch back and forth. It also has some nifty features like "break on next" - very cool! I can't wait til it's beta/mature. *hmm ... i guess that's literal - i can't wait. i'm using the alpha. ;)*

[grab firebug-1.4.0a31.xpi](http://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/1.4/)

Also since this is alpha softwre, I run this under a [different profile](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Managing+profiles) for my development and use the new features only when I need/want them. It's definitely not stable yet.

Answer (score 1):

> when I switch back to the console view my code is gone and I have to re-paste it

You can show previous commands in the firebug console by using the up/down keys.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but this still may be of use to those who find this question.

You could start an instance of Firebug Lite, using this bookmarklet, for example:

```
javascript:(function(F,i,r,e,b,u,g,L,I,T,E){if(F.getElementById(b))return;E=F[i+'NS']&&F.documentElement.namespaceURI;E=E?F[i+'NS'](E,'script'):F[i]('script');E[r]('id',b);E[r]('src',I+g+T);E[r](b,u);(F[e]('head')[0]||F[e]('body')[0]).appendChild(E);E=new%20Image;E[r]('src',I+L);})(document,'createElement','setAttribute','getElementsByTagName','FirebugLite','4','firebug-lite.js','releases/lite/latest/skin/xp/sprite.png','https://getfirebug.com/','#startOpened');
```

You can then have the HTML panel in the main Firebug extension, while having a console in the Firebug Lite bookmarklet.

I usually keep my main Firebug positioned on the right, which works out well as Firebug Lite renders on the bottom, and doesn't currently have a positioning option.